# html5 video tag not playing video on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, video, mobile

The html5 video tag is not playing the mp4 video. Below is the the html code we are using.

[image]

On the iphone, the video displays with a play button that the user is unable to click. On android devices, the video shows as a blakc banner.

I have tried adding js to play the video, but the video will still not play.

```
        startVideo: function() {
        var videoSources = $('video source');
        for (var i = 0; i < videoSources.length; i++) {
            var videoSource = videoSources[i];
            document.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
                videoSource.play();
            }, false);
        }
    }
```

When I hit the .mp4 url directly, I am able to play the video.

Has anyone run into this issue and have any suggestions on how to resolve it?